# Is it possible to create a struct based on an ID (ushort) without boxing and reflection?

Tags: c#

I have a byte[] where the first two bytes are a ushort which presents an ID that tells me what kind of data the rest of the array contains. Based on this ID I need to create a struct with its proper type to fill in the received data.

For now I thought that I maybe could use Dictionary, fill it on startup and afterwards get the proper type through it, but this includes lots of reflection and boxing as I get many byte[] to process.

Is there any possible solution without boxing and reflection to create the needed structtype based on the ushort ID?

EDIT:

```cs
public struct TestMessage
    {
        public const ushort typeCode = (ushort)Enums.MessageOpcodes.TestMessage;    
        public uint testuInt { internal set; get; }
        public ushort testuShort { internal set; get; }
        public ulong testuLong { internal set; get; }

        public TestMessage(uint uInt, ushort uShort, ulong uLong)
        {
            testuInt = uInt;
            testuShort = uShort;
            testuLong = uLong;
        }
    }
```

```cs
public static ReadOnlyDictionary<ushort, object> messageTypes;

private static void PopulateMessageDict()
        {
            var tempMessageTypes = new Dictionary<ushort, object>();

            tempMessageTypes.TryAdd(TestMessage.typeCode, new TestMessage());
            messageTypes = new ReadOnlyDictionary<ushort, object>(tempMessageTypes);
        }

public void TryAdd(this Dictionary<ushort, object> dictionary, ushort key, object value)
        {
            if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                dictionary.Add(key, value);                
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Key already exists in dictionary.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where does the boxing and reflection come from? Perhaps you should share the code you have. You can probably end up with something using structs implementing an interface, and generic methods with a type constraint using that interface, but it's hard to say what it should look like without more details on what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Get the 2 bytes and then switch case

Comment: @canton7 I added two snippets of what I tried to begin for now. The boxing in "TryAdd" when it converts the struct to an object is neglible as this only occures on startup. My first thought was, that I could get the object type with TryGetValue and GetType out of the dict and create the proper struct with it. But after some googling it seems that this wouldn't work well (if at all) as it would need reflection for each byte[] I want to process.

Comment: @Cid that would be my ultima ratio, but I thought I could get around it somehow.

Comment: And how do you want to use `messageTypes`? How are you going to deserialize into it? Is the plan to look at the first 2 bytes, use that to determine which struct to deserialize into, call into some other logic to deserialize into the right struct kind, and then pass that off... somewhere? Where? What happens once it's been deserialized, what then?

Comment: @canton7 exaclty. I want to determine on the 2 bytes which kind of struct is needed and then deserialize into its proper type to add it to a ConcurrentQueue to process it in another Thread.

Comment: Presumably each message type is processed in a different way?

Comment: Right, much like one message for some 2D positional data (Vector2 as two ints), one for a short 155 char message, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, based on your comments, I don't think you need the dictionary at all.

You said you want to take some bytes, look at the the first 2 to determine the message type, then deserialize into a message of the correct type and then process it in a way specific to that type.

So at a very high level, what you want is:

```
var opCode = (Enums.MessageOpcodes)(data[0] << 8 | data[1]);
switch (opCode)
{
    case Enums.MessageOpcodes.TestMessage:
        ProcessTestMessage(data);
        break;
    case Enums.MessageOpcodes.VectorMessage:
        ProcessVectorMessage(data);
        break;        
}
```

Then your `ProcessTestMessage` method deserializes into a `TestMessage` struct and then processes it; likewise your `ProcessVectorMessage` and the `VectorMessage` struct.

You can generalize this a bit:

```
interface IMessageProcessor
{
    Enums.MessageOpcodes Opcode { get; }
    void DeserializeAndProcess(byte[] data);
}
```

Then:

```
class TestMessageProcessor : IMessageProcessor
{
    public Enums.MessageOpcodes Opcode => Enums.MessageOpcodes.TestMessage;
    public void DeserializeAndProcess(byte[] data)
    {
        // Deserialize into a TestMessage
        // Process
    }
}
```

Then you have your `Dictionary<Enums.MessageOpcodes, IMessageProcessor>` (or at this point, since the key is a property on the `IMessageProcessor` you can use a `KeyedCollection`):

```
class MessageProcessorLookup : KeyedCollection<Enums.MessageOpcodes, IMessageProcessor>
{
    public override Enums.MessageOpcodes GetKeyForItem(IMessageProcessor item) => item.Opcode;
}
```

Then:

```
var lookup = new MessageProcessorLookup() { new TestMessageProcessor(), .... };
...
lookup[opcode].DeserializeAndProcess(data);
```

Ultimately, if you have a bunch of different structs, and you don't want to box them, you *cannot* have code which says "deserialize this data into an appropriate struct -- I don't care what sort -- then give it back to me", as you are going to have to box the struct to give it back. Likewise you can't say "deserialize this data into an appropriate struct and then push it onto this ConcurrentQueue which handles all message types" without boxing. All processing has to be "forward-only", with the method which deserializes into the struct calling onwards into the method which processes it.